# Use find to select some directory

Tags: shell-script

I wish to use find (or ls) in a script to select some directory (maybe several directories actually) according to some variable I give.

So for ex :

```
/usr/local/bin/script action tad*
```

would give me a list of all the directories (only dirs) beginning with "tad" in repository /var/db (only that repository, no recursive, this is a conf' variable coded in the script).

Not

```
/var/db/tadam.fr
/var/db/tadadada.dk
/var/db/taddeus.com
```

but

```
tadam.fr
tadadada.dk
taddeus.com
```

Edit : that script is to maintain some dns zones. Each of the dirs (taddeus.com & others) contains the various elements of a dns zone.

So the script should call the "action" on the various zones selected.

At present, the script runs well when called for a specific zone. I just wish to be able to performs several operations in a row.

Calling

```
script check taddeus.com
```

checks that the zone is loaded correctly and without errors.

So I would like the same with *tad* (for ex).

Comment: How does your script `script` look like? What is your final goal?  Are you interested in only directories or files too?

Comment: Do you want to search recursively, or just in the specified directly?

Comment: What's the next step after you gather this directory, or these multiple directories? Passing filenames around can be tricky, given the valid bytes in a filename.  Is "/var/db" the specific directory you want to search in -- is that to be hard-coded into the script?

Comment: I added precision about the purpose and the way it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
find /path/to/folder -name "tad*" -exec basename {} \;
```

/path/to/folder - path where you want start your search. You should put there / if you want search from the root.